# Wait until $.ajax completes without using $.when

Tags: jquery

In my project I have to use jQuery 1.4.x. I have four async $.ajax functions firing off, and all return true/false. I am needing to wait to evaluate them in an IF, because if I do them now, not all are finished firing.

Code(all in $(document).ready..:`

```
    function getHTTPStatusCode200(urlIn) {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlIn,
            complete: function (xhr) {
                return (xhr.status == 200);
            }
        });
    }
```

There are four of those, and I need to do something like this:

```
if(getHTTPStatusCode200(url) && getHTTPStatusCode401(url)){
     alert("It worked.");
}
```

`

Comment: How about inside that complete handler, seems like a good place to stick the condition.

Comment: since you're such an old version of jQuery, id suggest you use `async: false` in each of ajax calls if youre running them sequentially. Beware that `async` will block your browser until the `ajax` is done

Comment: That is *exactly* what `when` is for. Why is that not an option? Was it not around in 1.4?

Comment: @ogc-nick beacuse OPs using v1.4. `when` was introduced in v.1.5

Comment: Please check out my answer below. I have provided a full replacement method to implement `$.when`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.when` concept is not hard to mimic:

```
var results = [];
function newResult(result) {
    results.push(result);
    if (results.length === 4) {
        alert("It worked.");
    }
}

function getHTTPStatusCode200(urlIn) {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlIn,
        complete: function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                newResult(xhr);
            }
        }
    });
}

// your other functions, each calling newResult when done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you don't have deferred objects doesn't mean you cant use callbacks.

```
function getHTTPStatusCode200(urlIn,callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlIn,
        complete: function (xhr) {
            callback(xhr.status)
        }
    });
}

getHTTPStatusCode200("foo.php",function(status){
    alert(status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A non blocking solution and just as fast is to call them asynchronously but sequentially via the success callback:

Define your method so that it returns the ajax object.

```
function getHTTPStatusCode200(urlIn) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: urlIn
    });
}
```

Then chain them:

```
getHTTPStatusCode200(url1).complete(function(xhr1){
    getHTTPStatusCode200(url2).complete(function(xhr2){
        getHTTPStatusCode200(url3).complete(function(xhr3){
            getHTTPStatusCode200(url4).complete(function(xhr4){
                //all requests have been completed and you have access to all responses
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working on this as a direct substitute for $.when:

```
$.when = function() {
    this.requests = [];
    this.completeFunc;
    this.interval;

    //if you want it to work jsut like $.when use this
    this.requests = arguments;
    //If you want to pass in URLs use this
    //for(var i in arguments) {
    //    this.requests.push($.get(arguments[i]));
    //};

    this.complete = function(func) {
        this.completeFunc = func;
        var when = this;
        this.interval = window.setInterval(function(){
            checkReadyStates(when)
        }, 100);
        return this;
    };

    var checkReadyStates = function(when) {
        var complete = 0;
        for(var i in when.requests) {
            if(when.requests[i].readyState==4) {
                complete++;
            }
        }
        if(complete == when.requests.length) {
            window.clearInterval(when.interval);
            when.completeFunc.apply(when, when.requests);
        }
    };

    return this;
}

function handler(){ 
    console.log('handler');
    console.log(arguments);
    //The arguments here are all of the completed ajax requests
    //see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR
}

$.when(xhr1,xhr2,xhr3).complete(handler);
//or
//$.when('index.php','index2.php','index3.php').complete(handler);
```

Tested now and works.

Answer (score -1):

Add `async:false`, like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: urlIn,
        async: false,
        complete: function (xhr) {
            return (xhr.status == 200);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you still can't return out of a callback like that, and async: false is a bad practice.

Comment: This is the way to go ........ if you're trying to lock the browser and annoy your users.

Comment: You guys are assuming a heavy-use app, with (relatively) long processing times for each ajax call. OP is best judge of this. In my projects, there are several where an `async:false` is helpful and does not impact the users' experience in any way that a human could notice -- even with a stopwatch. Every project's different.

Comment: Until you have a high-latency connection, for whatever reason. It's utterly unnecessary in this context. The only real case when `async: false` is a good idea is in an `onbeforeunload` callback. Note that, as @KevinB says, you can't do that return anyway.

Comment: Okay, guys, thanks for the comments. I am grateful for your corrections.